# Symbol cannot be found

Tags: java, variables

sorry if this is a simple question but i am new to java and rather frustrated.
i have a class `Hostel` and a class `Main`. in the `Hostel` class i have the variable `myString` and i am trying to use it to occupy a textarea called `output` in `Main` when button `findRoomB` is clicked but i am told the variable cannot be found.

Below is the code in the `Main` class where the error is shown

```
findRoomB.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            HostelClass find = new HostelClass();
            ouput.setText(myString);
        }
});
```

error: cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable myString

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please list the actual error.

Comment: try `output.setText(myString);`

Comment: how is myString of the outer class declared ?

Comment: the error seems to be rooting from the fact that myString is a member of HostelClass  where as you are trying to access it as if it were a member / local variable in Main. Associate `myString` with `find` and I guess you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve myString from the find instance of HostelClass:

```
output.setText(find.getMyString())
```

or

```
// if you're using direct access of a public member, but I don't recommended this
output.setText(find.myString)
```

Comment: Exactly. I absolutely **hate** downvotes without comments. You have my sympathy. +1 for a good answer. :)